# What is the most general Self-Adjoint operator acting on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, quantum-mechanics

What is the most general Self-Adjoint operator acting on $L^{2}\mathbb{R}$?

My hypothesis is that the aswer to my question will be that the most general Self-Adjoint operator $A$ acting on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ is a non linear combination of terms involving the so called position and momentum operators $X$ and $P$ defined as follows for some $\psi(x)\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$

$$ X\psi(x) = x\psi(x)   \:\: (Multiplication\:\: operator)$$
$$ P\psi(x) = -i\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \psi(x)$$

these operators satisfy the commutation relation $[X,P]= i\mathbb{I}$.

Would the most general $A$ be just some general operator valued fucntion $f(X,P)$ of $X$ and $P$?

Comment: The most general self adjoint operator is of the type $\frac {T+T^{*}} 2$ where $T$ is an arbitatry operator.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you for the response! This was very helpful. Any idea what the most general operator acting on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ might look like? I think that therein lies my conundrum. Thank you for your time. I imagine that the answer is that it would be some non linear combiantion of multipliaction and differential operatotrs.

Comment: I just realized that integral operators would have to considered as well.

Comment: Any self-adjoint $A : L^2(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is automatically bounded because self-adjoint operators are closed. The differentiation operator you cite is not defined on all of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. A selfadjoint multiplication operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is multiplication by a bounded real function.